# Use properties moz-transition and webkit-transition in tag p:inputText

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I want to use properties `-moz-transition` and `webkit-transition` in attribute `style` of tag `<p:inputText>`. I try to add it but it not run. Can I do it?

Comment: This will work on any browser supporting webkit. What is the relationship of these styles with JSF / PrimeFaces?

Comment: Please add a sample code

Comment: Yes. I want to a page login the same [link](http://codepen.io/sevilayha/pen/IdGKH) . And Instead of I use tag input in html, I used tag p:inputText

Comment: I added it, but not work like I thought... Instead of characters is moved, then it resize width of field <code>inputText</code>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the [link](http://codepen.io/sevilayha/pen/IdGKH) you mentioned in comments. copied the css.

I have added

```
input:focus {
  -webkit-animation:inputHighlighter 1s ease;
  -moz-animation:inputHighlighter 1s ease;
  animation:inputHighlighter 1s ease;
}


/* ANIMATIONS ================ */
@-webkit-keyframes inputHighlighter {
    from { background:#5264AE; }
    to  { width:0; background:transparent; }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes inputHighlighter {
   from { background:#5264AE; }
  to    { width:0; background:transparent; }
 }
 @keyframes inputHighlighter {
    from { background:#5264AE; }
    to  { width:0; background:transparent; }
  }
```

in my css file

I did not add any style attribute in my p:inputText. I see the animations on primefaces inputText without any issues. If you had added code like @Phate01 answered, they could have found the mistake. Maybe you added animation declarations along with the calls in style attribute itself? So this is not primefaces issue.

My envirmonment: Primefaces 5.3 Mojarra 2.2.10 EAP 6.4 JDK 8

Comment: so, I can use the other way?

Comment: That's right. I want to this effect in my form login.

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding. Please add the styles in css file. And then just code plain p:inputText in login page . You are all set

Comment: This is my form login [link](https://ideone.com/fork/5Ykb0R) . And then css file [link](https://ideone.com/fork/k53woo).  I don't know more about css. Thanks.

Comment: Hey. Your css [link](https://ideone.com/fork/k53woo) is the issue. After line 23 in there just add the copy and pase the css code in my answer and try again. Let me know